# make rest calls to other microservices with undertow

Tags: asynchttpclient, undertow

I have a simple websocket server using undertow.

How to make HTTP calls to other microservices using UndertowClient from within this method?

Any pointers ?

```
@OnMessage
public String onMessage(String message) {
    //Receive request -- make async micro call - Response will be sent later
    return "request received";
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Taken from here:
https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/blob/master/websockets-jsr/src/test/java/io/undertow/websockets/jsr/test/JsrWebSocketServer07Test.java

---

```
import io.undertow.websockets.utils.WebSocketTestClient;
...
WebSocketTestClient client = new WebSocketTestClient(getVersion(), new URI("ws://" + NetworkUtils.formatPossibleIpv6Address(DefaultServer.getHostAddress("default")) + ":" + DefaultServer.getHostPort("default") + "/"));
    client.connect();
    client.send(new BinaryWebSocketFrame(Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(payload)), new FrameChecker(BinaryWebSocketFrame.class, payload, latch));
    latch.getIoFuture().get();
    Assert.assertNull(cause.get());
    client.destroy();
```

Comment: It's best to explain your code so that the asker understands the solution.